# Is there a way to compare two excel sheet files with tcl?

Tags: excel, tcl

I am currently using TCOM to work on excel using TCL. I have 2 excel sheet files. What i need to do is compare the two files for differences and list them out in txt file/excel. 
I would like to know whether this comparison between two excel files can be done using tcl/tcom.

Comment: Should be possible (I'll let someone else talk you through how; I'm not on the right OS at the moment to test it myself). But I thought that Excel these days came with a built in spreadsheet comparison tool…

Comment: Do you mind exporting to csv?

Answer (score 0):

If you working on a linux environment you could use some bash commands to help you out.

I think the best way to quickly process their data would be through csv files. You could use:

```
exec sort sheet1.csv
exec sort sheet2.csv
set diff [diff sheet1.csv sheet2.csv]
```

Editing since this isn't a pure Tcl:

Let's say both of your csv files looks like this:
sheet1.csv -> a,b,c,d
sheet2.csv -> a,d,c,e

You can load these files by passing them as argument to your Tcl file:
myTclFile sheet1.csv sheet2.csv

Inside your Tcl you could read them using [argv](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1623):

```
set list1 [lindex $argv 0]
set list2 [lindex $argv 1]
```

It is good practice to check for input files before invoking them.
If order of the files aren't important but only the fact that they have the same data you could use [lsort](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsort.htm). Nevertheless, in order to turn this into a actual list of elements, instead of one big string use **split**:

```
set list1 [split $list1 ',']
set list2 [split $list2 ',']
```

Then you can iterate over these list the way you want. My suggestion would be using **foreach**. This would go more or less like this (exempla if you wanted to iterate over whole lists)

```
foreach element $list1 {
    foreach element2 $list2 {
        set hasMatch 0
        if {$element == $element2} {
             incr hasMatch
             break
        } else {
            continue
        }
    }
    if {!$hasMatch} {
        set diff [lappend $diff $element]
    } else {
        continue                                                                                                                                                                                 
    }
}
```